# Create a collection of Windows Services matching a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, servicecontroller

I want to create a collection of Windows Services that will match a regular expression using a `Where` clause.

For example, I have 3 Windows Services called:

RCLoad1
RCLoad2
RCLoad3

my Regex would be something like: "^RCLoad*"

I'd like to use something like:

```
ServiceController[] myServices = ServiceController.GetServices(ServerName)
    .Where Regex.IsMatch(....)
```

But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Just replace `*` with `[0-9]+$`, `^RCLoad[0-9]+$`

Comment: Why not just `Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("RCLoad"))`?

Comment: If `RCLoad` or `RCLoada` are not to be matched, `.StartsWith("RCLoad")` won't be enough. However, right now, it is really not clear what the requirements are, @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly, I was basing on the fact that the OP didn't mention of a possible `RCLoad` or `RCLoad4` that had to be avoided.

Comment: RCLoad and such were just examples. It could be anything with 'RCLoad' in it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clear on the exact failure.

Does `GetServices(ServerName)` actually return a list of items?

Subsequently you don't mention what property has the name of the server, Is it `Name`? **Because the code you have now takes the objects `ToString()` which most likely defaults to the type name** and hence the failure. (?)

Find the right *name* property and use the pattern `RCLoad`, which will find it anywhere in the string, and then put into a `ToList()` such as

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"RCLoad"); // RCLoad can be anywhere in the string.

var controllers = ServiceController.GetServices(ServerName)
                                   .Where(sc => rgx.IsMatch( sc.Name )) 
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Sweet!!  Fits my needs. Thanks.